# How to plot binary tree structure using a function in C#

Tags: c#

I have written the function to build binary tree and it works but I don't know how to plot the tree in my interface.
The function I have written to find binary tree looks like this:

```
private Node BuildTreeFromPostAndMid(string Post, string Mid)
{
    char genc=Post[Post.Length - 1];
    Node gen = new Node(genc);
    string[] s = Mid.Split(genc);

    if (s[0] != "")
    {
        int l1 = s[0].Length;
        string newh = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Post.Length - l1 + 1; i++)
        {
            if (IsSame(Post.Substring(i, l1), s[0]))
            {
                newh = Post.Substring(i, l1);
            }
        }
        gen.lc = BuildTreeFromPostAndMid(newh, s[0]);
    }
    else gen.lc = null;

    if (s[1] != "")
    {
        int l2 = s[1].Length;
        string newh = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Post.Length - l2 + 1; i++)
        {
            if (IsSame(Post.Substring(i, l2), s[1]))
            {
                newh = Post.Substring(i, l2);
            }
        }
        gen.rc = BuildTreeFromPostAndMid(newh, s[1]);
    }
    else gen.rc = null;

    return gen;
}
```

In the UI, the user can input Post order and mid order traversal binary tree series, and I should plot the tree in somewhere in my interface (I haven't enough credit to upload my picture, so I type it, hope you can understand what I say)

Comment: That entirely depends on what the "interface" uses for a framework. WPF, WinForms, GTK, ASP, etc...

Comment: My file name is WPF, so I think It's WPF, maybe.

Comment: Then maybe we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar a couple of years ago in Silverlight, WPF and WinForms. You have multiple options.

1. Use a standard TreeView control, I initially did this in WinForms. It won't be as pretty as other solutions but it's fast to implement. You can put some work into it and customize it if need be. This has been done already, for example go [here](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1401031).
2. Build the UI tree through nested control containers. Each container is in fact a node, it contains the data of the current node, and its children (a container for each child and so on). It's going to be a recursive structure, that's how I displayed my tree in Silverlight and WPF. It was simple to implement, the alignment is made automatically, I think I used a StackPanel as a container and defined a custom control to display the current node. But be careful, it might cause performance issues depending on the depth of your tree (exponential growth), however, we didn't have any.
3. Build the UI tree in a canvas, that's how I eventually did it in WinForms. This would take a bit more work since you need to take care of the alignment yourself. As a rough guide, the width of your canvas will be split by the number of leaves you have, and the height is split into the levels of the tree. You basically do a DFS on the tree and add the nodes to your canvas, from bottom to top. As I said you have to do more work to get the alignment right but it might be worth it.
4. Research for custom controls that suit your need, I am pretty sure you will find some, this is a not a rarely seen issue, having to display a tree sstructure.